# SMJobBless.py script doesn't work on M1 Macs

Tags: macos, apple-m1, smjobbless, service-management

The [`SMJobBlessUtil.py`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SMJobBless/Listings/SMJobBlessUtil_py.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010071-SMJobBlessUtil_py-DontLinkElementID_8) script (which Apple provides for setting/checking the pairing between a privileged helper tool and its main app) does not work on M1 Macs.

```sh
$ ./SMJobBlessUtil.py check MyApp.app

/Users/Alex/MyApp.app/Contents/Library/LaunchServices/ca.momchilov.MyApp.helper: tool __TEXT / __info_plist section dump malformed (2)
```

I have filed a bug report under `rdar://FB9726189`, which you can see here on Open Radar: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5006748255518720

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I debugged this by putting in some calls to `traceback.print_exc()` throughout the script, because its default behaviour doesn't print stack traces.

### How it should work

The problem stems from the `readPlistFromToolSection` funciton, which uses [`otool`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/OSX/1/otool/) to read some sections out of the helper tool's executable (which is Mach-O file, which is broken into many sections. Some of those section are embedded plist files).

It invokes:

```sh
$ otool -s __TEXT __info_plist <YOUR_APP>/Contents/Library/LaunchServices/<YOUR_HELPER_TOOL>
```

(it also invokes a similar variant for `__launchd_plist`)

Running this tool on an tool compiled for x86 (either natively, or via Rosetta) gives a result like:

```
./your_helper_tool:
Contents of (__TEXT,__info_plist) section
0000000100003b8a    3c 3f 78 6d 6c 20 76 65 72 73 69 6f 6e 3d 22 31 
0000000100003b9a    2e 30 22 20 65 6e 63 6f 64 69 6e 67 3d 22 55 54 
0000000100003baa    46 2d 38 22 3f 3e 0a 3c 21 44 4f 43 54 59 50 45 
0000000100003bba    20 70 6c 69 73 74 20 50 55 42 4c 49 43 20 22 2d 
0000000100003bca    2f 2f 41 70 70 6c 65 2f 2f 44 54 44 20 50 4c 49 
0000000100003bda    53 54 20 31 2e 30 2f 2f 45 4e 22 20 22 68 74 74 
0000000100003bea    70 3a 2f 2f 77 77 77 2e 61 70 70 6c 65 2e 63 6f 
0000000100003bfa    6d 2f 44 54 44 73 2f 50 72 6f 70 65 72 74 79 4c 
0000000100003c0a    69 73 74 2d 31 2e 30 2e 64 74 64 22 3e 0a 3c 70 
0000000100003c1a    6c 69 73 74 20 76 65 72 73 69 6f 6e 3d 22 31 2e 
0000000100003c2a    30 22 3e 0a 3c 64 69 63 74 3e 0a 09 3c 6b 65 79 
0000000100003c3a    3e 43 46 42 75 6e 64 6c 65 49 64 65 6e 74 69 66 
0000000100003c4a    69 65 72 3c 2f 6b 65 79 3e 0a 09 3c 73 74 72 69 
0000000100003c5a    6e 67 3e 63 61 2e 6d 6f 6d 63 68 69 6c 6f 76 2e 
0000000100003c6a    44 65 6d 6f 2d 50 72 69 76 69 6c 65 67 65 64 2d 
0000000100003c7a    48 65 6c 70 65 72 2d 41 70 70 2e 68 65 6c 70 65 
0000000100003c8a    72 3c 2f 73 74 72 69 6e 67 3e 0a 09 3c 6b 65 79 
0000000100003c9a    3e 43 46 42 75 6e 64 6c 65 49 6e 66 6f 44 69 63 
0000000100003caa    74 69 6f 6e 61 72 79 56 65 72 73 69 6f 6e 3c 2f 
0000000100003cba    6b 65 79 3e 0a 09 3c 73 74 72 69 6e 67 3e 36 2e 
0000000100003cca    30 3c 2f 73 74 72 69 6e 67 3e 0a 09 3c 6b 65 79 
0000000100003cda    3e 43 46 42 75 6e 64 6c 65 4e 61 6d 65 3c 2f 6b 
0000000100003cea    65 79 3e 0a 09 3c 73 74 72 69 6e 67 3e 44 65 6d 
0000000100003cfa    6f 50 72 69 76 69 6c 65 67 65 64 48 65 6c 70 65 
0000000100003d0a    72 3c 2f 73 74 72 69 6e 67 3e 0a 09 3c 6b 65 79 
0000000100003d1a    3e 43 46 42 75 6e 64 6c 65 56 65 72 73 69 6f 6e 
0000000100003d2a    3c 2f 6b 65 79 3e 0a 09 3c 73 74 72 69 6e 67 3e 
0000000100003d3a    31 2e 30 3c 2f 73 74 72 69 6e 67 3e 0a 09 3c 6b 
0000000100003d4a    65 79 3e 53 4d 41 75 74 68 6f 72 69 7a 65 64 43 
0000000100003d5a    6c 69 65 6e 74 73 3c 2f 6b 65 79 3e 0a 09 3c 61 
0000000100003d6a    72 72 61 79 3e 0a 09 09 3c 73 74 72 69 6e 67 3e 
0000000100003d7a    69 64 65 6e 74 69 66 69 65 72 20 22 63 61 2e 6d 
0000000100003d8a    6f 6d 63 68 69 6c 6f 76 2e 44 65 6d 6f 2d 50 72 
0000000100003d9a    69 76 69 6c 65 67 65 64 2d 48 65 6c 70 65 72 2d 
0000000100003daa    41 70 70 22 20 61 6e 64 20 61 6e 63 68 6f 72 20 
0000000100003dba    61 70 70 6c 65 20 67 65 6e 65 72 69 63 20 61 6e 
0000000100003dca    64 20 63 65 72 74 69 66 69 63 61 74 65 20 6c 65 
0000000100003dda    61 66 5b 73 75 62 6a 65 63 74 2e 43 4e 5d 20 3d 
0000000100003dea    20 22 41 70 70 6c 65 20 44 65 76 65 6c 6f 70 6d 
0000000100003dfa    65 6e 74 3a 20 61 6c 65 78 61 6e 64 65 72 6d 6f 
0000000100003e0a    6d 63 68 69 6c 6f 76 40 67 6d 61 69 6c 2e 63 6f 
0000000100003e1a    6d 20 28 4c 43 52 33 32 34 54 51 38 35 29 22 20 
0000000100003e2a    61 6e 64 20 63 65 72 74 69 66 69 63 61 74 65 20 
0000000100003e3a    31 5b 66 69 65 6c 64 2e 31 2e 32 2e 38 34 30 2e 
0000000100003e4a    31 31 33 36 33 35 2e 31 30 30 2e 36 2e 32 2e 31 
0000000100003e5a    5d 20 2f 2a 20 65 78 69 73 74 73 20 2a 2f 3c 2f 
0000000100003e6a    73 74 72 69 6e 67 3e 0a 09 3c 2f 61 72 72 61 79 
0000000100003e7a    3e 0a 3c 2f 64 69 63 74 3e 0a 3c 2f 70 6c 69 73 
0000000100003e8a    74 3e 0a
```

The `SMJobBlessUtil.py` script then processes this down into a XML plist file by:

1. Striping off the first two lines
2. Stripping off the addresses in the left-most column (everything before the `\t` of each line)
3. Splitting each line on spaces, to obtain 16 pairs of hexits (each encoding 1 byte)
4. Converting that into a `bytearray`, that's then parsed by `plistlib.readPlistFromString`

### The issue

When you run the same `otool` command on a native ARM64 compiled binary, the issue becomes obvious:

```
./your_helper_tool:
Contents of (__TEXT,__info_plist) section
0000000100003b5a    6d783f3c 6576206c 6f697372 31223d6e 
0000000100003b6a    2022302e 6f636e65 676e6964 5455223d 
0000000100003b7a    22382d46 3c0a3e3f 434f4421 45505954 
0000000100003b8a    696c7020 50207473 494c4255 2d222043 
0000000100003b9a    70412f2f 2f656c70 4454442f 494c5020 
0000000100003baa    31205453 2f2f302e 20224e45 74746822 
0000000100003bba    2f2f3a70 2e777777 6c707061 6f632e65 
0000000100003bca    54442f6d 502f7344 65706f72 4c797472 
0000000100003bda    2d747369 2e302e31 22647464 703c0a3e 
0000000100003bea    7473696c 72657620 6e6f6973 2e31223d 
0000000100003bfa    0a3e2230 6369643c 090a3e74 79656b3c 
0000000100003c0a    4246433e 6c646e75 65644965 6669746e 
0000000100003c1a    3c726569 79656b2f 3c090a3e 69727473 
0000000100003c2a    633e676e 6f6d2e61 6968636d 2e766f6c 
0000000100003c3a    6f6d6544 6972502d 656c6976 2d646567 
0000000100003c4a    706c6548 412d7265 682e7070 65706c65 
0000000100003c5a    732f3c72 6e697274 090a3e67 79656b3c 
0000000100003c6a    4246433e 6c646e75 666e4965 6369446f 
0000000100003c7a    6e6f6974 56797261 69737265 2f3c6e6f 
0000000100003c8a    3e79656b 733c090a 6e697274 2e363e67 
0000000100003c9a    732f3c30 6e697274 090a3e67 79656b3c 
0000000100003caa    4246433e 6c646e75 6d614e65 6b2f3c65 
0000000100003cba    0a3e7965 74733c09 676e6972 6d65443e 
0000000100003cca    6972506f 656c6976 48646567 65706c65 
0000000100003cda    732f3c72 6e697274 090a3e67 79656b3c 
0000000100003cea    4246433e 6c646e75 72655665 6e6f6973 
0000000100003cfa    656b2f3c 090a3e79 7274733c 3e676e69 
0000000100003d0a    3c302e31 7274732f 3e676e69 6b3c090a 
0000000100003d1a    533e7965 7475414d 69726f68 4364657a 
0000000100003d2a    6e65696c 2f3c7374 3e79656b 613c090a 
0000000100003d3a    79617272 09090a3e 7274733c 3e676e69 
0000000100003d4a    6e656469 69666974 22207265 6d2e6163 
0000000100003d5a    68636d6f 766f6c69 6d65442e 72502d6f 
0000000100003d6a    6c697669 64656765 6c65482d 2d726570 
0000000100003d7a    22707041 646e6120 636e6120 20726f68 
0000000100003d8a    6c707061 65672065 6972656e 6e612063 
0000000100003d9a    65632064 66697472 74616369 656c2065 
0000000100003daa    735b6661 656a6275 432e7463 3d205d4e 
0000000100003dba    70412220 20656c70 65766544 6d706f6c 
0000000100003dca    3a746e65 656c6120 646e6178 6f6d7265 
0000000100003dda    6968636d 40766f6c 69616d67 6f632e6c 
0000000100003dea    4c28206d 32335243 38515434 20222935 
0000000100003dfa    20646e61 74726563 63696669 20657461 
0000000100003e0a    69665b31 2e646c65 2e322e31 2e303438 
0000000100003e1a    36333131 312e3533 362e3030 312e322e 
0000000100003e2a    2a2f205d 69786520 20737473 2f3c2f2a 
0000000100003e3a    69727473 0a3e676e 612f3c09 79617272 
0000000100003e4a    2f3c0a3e 74636964 2f3c0a3e 73696c70 
0000000100003e5a    74 3e 0a
```

The bytes are clumped into groups of 4, and each group is reversed. I.e. instead of the expected format:

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p
```

You get:

```
dcba hgfe lkji ponm
```

### The solution

There are two main solutions I can think of for this:

1. Build your project for Rosetta (even if you don't intend to ship it as such)  and use `SMJobBless.py` on that result. If the `check` command passes for that, I think it's pretty reasonable to assume it would pass for a native ARM binary, too.
2. Patch the script to fix its parsing logic. Here's my modification to it, which worked for me:

```
diff --git a/SMJobBlessUtil.py b/SMJobBlessUtil.py
index 1a5dd74ea2900ac2fae10b7448272fe4a7d37c7e..487e022a8ff96b4fb86ffe837dbd758853d680a8 100755
--- a/SMJobBlessUtil.py 
+++ b/SMJobBlessUtil.py 
@@ -152,16 +152,37 @@ def readPlistFromToolSection(toolPath, segmentName, sectionName):
         raise CheckException("tool %s / %s section dump malformed (1)" % (segmentName, sectionName), toolPath)
     del plistLines[0:2]
 
+    # Reshapes an input like "6d783f3c" into an output like "3c 3f 78 6d"
+    def reshape(input):
+        hexit_pairs = [input[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(input), 2)]
+        hexit_pairs.reverse()
+        return " ".join(hexit_pairs)
+
     try:
         bytes = []
         for line in plistLines:
-            # line looks like this:
+            # line should look like this:
             #
             # '0000000100000b80\t3c 3f 78 6d 6c 20 76 65 72 73 69 6f 6e 3d 22 31 '
+            #
+            # But it actually looks like:
+            # '0000000100003b5a\t6d783f3c 6576206c 6f697372 31223d6e
             columns = line.split("\t")
             assert len(columns) == 2
-            for hexStr in columns[1].split():
+
+            hex_data = columns[1]
+            four_byte_chunks = hex_data.split()
+            # print("four_byte_chunks" + str(four_byte_chunks))
+
+            reshaped = [reshape(four_byte_chunk) for four_byte_chunk in four_byte_chunks]
+            # print("reshaped" + str(reshaped))
+
+            fixed_line = " ".join(reshaped)
+            # print("fixed_line: '" + str(fixed_line) + "'")
+
+            for hexStr in fixed_line.split():
                 bytes.append(int(hexStr, 16))
+
         plist = plistlib.readPlistFromString(bytearray(bytes))
     except:
         raise CheckException("tool %s / %s section dump malformed (2)" % (segmentName, sectionName), toolPath)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question here. Much appreciated!

Comment: @LucasDerraugh hahaha hi lucas, fancy seeing you here :)

Comment: Ya, the circle is small for answers to Mac questions.